# Getting Error for @CucumberOptions and seems cucumber.class deprecated

Tags: automated-tests, cucumber-java, cucumber-junit

[My Test Runner Class][1]

I tried to create TestRunner Class (using Eclipse-Java11-Cucumber-Maven); however getting error for CucumberOptions annotation and seems Cucumber.class is deprecated. Please let me know how to solve this?
Please see attached image.

Also, below is the Test Runner Code:

```
package TestRunner;

import io.cucumber.junit.platform.engine.Cucumber;
import io.cucumber.junit.platform.*;
import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;


@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        feature = "src\\test\\java\\AppFeatures",
        glue = "StepDefinitions")

public class Runner {
    
}
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/etCZ6.png
```

Comment: Can you please add your code as text instead of an image. And include your dependencies?

Comment: @Marit Below is the Runner Class
package TestRunner;

import io.cucumber.junit.platform.engine.Cucumber;
import io.cucumber.junit.platform.*;
import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;


@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
  feature = "src\\test\\java\\AppFeatures",
  glue = "StepDefinitions")

public class Runner {
 
}

Comment: Can you please update your question itself with the relevant info? That will make it easier for people to read your question and help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the source code for `io.cucumber.junit.platform.engine.Cucumber` you'll see that:

https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/blob/main/junit-platform-engine/src/main/java/io/cucumber/junit/platform/engine/Cucumber.java

```java
package io.cucumber.junit.platform.engine;

import org.apiguardian.api.API;
import org.apiguardian.api.API.Status;
import org.junit.platform.commons.annotation.Testable;

import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

/**
 * Test discovery annotation. Marks the package of the annotated class for test
 * discovery.
 * <p>
 * Maven and Gradle do not support the
 * {@link org.junit.platform.engine.discovery.DiscoverySelectors} used by
 * Cucumber. As a workaround Cucumber will scan the package of the annotated
 * class for feature files and execute them.
 * <p>
 * Note about Testable: While this class is annotated with @Testable the
 * recommended way for IDEs and other tooling use the selectors implemented by
 * Cucumber to discover feature files.
 * <p>
 * 
 * @deprecated Please use the JUnit Platform Suite to run Cucumber in
 *             combination with Surefire or Gradle. E.g: <code><pre>{@code
 *package com.example;
 *
 *import org.junit.platform.suite.api.ConfigurationParameter;
 *import org.junit.platform.suite.api.SelectClasspathResource;
 *import org.junit.platform.suite.api.Suite;
 *
 *import static io.cucumber.junit.platform.engine.Constants.GLUE_PROPERTY_NAME;
 *
 *&#64;Suite
 *&#64;SelectClasspathResource("com/example")
 *&#64;ConfigurationParameter(
 *   key = GLUE_PROPERTY_NAME,
 *   value = "com.example"
 *)
 *public class RunCucumberTest {
 *}
 *}</pre></code>
 * @see        CucumberTestEngine
 */
@API(status = Status.DEPRECATED)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Testable
@Deprecated
public @interface Cucumber {

}
```

If you are using Maven you can download the sources with `mvn dependency:sources`. Though typically you won't have to as your IDE can do this for you.

Now there are a few things to observe here:

1. If you search for the JUnit Platform you'll find that it is part of JUnit 5. However `@RunWith` is part of JUnit 4.

   This means that you are mixing different framework versions together. You can not expect that to work.
2. There is a code snippet in the Javadoc that suggests the correct way to use Cucumber with JUnit 5.

```java
package com.example;

import org.junit.platform.suite.api.ConfigurationParameter;
import org.junit.platform.suite.api.IncludeEngines;
import org.junit.platform.suite.api.SelectClasspathResource;
import org.junit.platform.suite.api.Suite;

import static io.cucumber.junit.platform.engine.Constants.GLUE_PROPERTY_NAME;

@Suite
@IncludeEngines("cucumber")
@SelectClasspathResource("com/example")
@ConfigurationParameter(key = GLUE_PROPERTY_NAME, value = "com.example")
public class RunCucumberTest {
}
```

You should consider using that.

Each open source project is different but it's also good to look at the source. Documentation may be included:

https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/main/junit-platform-engine

And since this is a JUnit 5 engine, the JUnit 5 documentation is good to read too.

https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/

Comment: Thank you @M.P. Korstanje. ... I was using dependencies used in cucumber-java-skeleton/pom.xml (https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-java-skeleton/blob/main/pom.xml) .... on top of that, i had to add couple of more and then it worked for me ..... Thanks

Comment: I added following dependencies :
junit-jupiter-api, 
junit, 
cucumber-junit, 
selenium-java, 
junit-vintage-engine  ... with exclusion .... hamcrest-core

Comment: You may want to remove some dependencies again. You're now using JUnit 4 thourhg JUnit 5. Generally people want to use only JUnit 5.